# Voice processing for audio ident.

Tags: voice, processing

I'm in the process of creating an audio ident for a website I'll be launching soon. I had a great voice actor record a number of takes and I have been playing with these for a few days now. However, I can't seem to find any suitable effects for voice processing.

I really love the nVidia ident that's in a lot of video games these days. I tried reverb, compression, delays, phasers, flangers and I'm not nearly content with the result.

What would you guys recommend I use? Is there a secret amount of some fx or a specific effect that works best?

Thanks,
G.

Comment: Do you have an audible example that you can provide us?  That may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the right style of voice and performance, which are in the ballpark of what you're looking to achieve. Then edit and process it however possible until it sounds like something nice, without destroying it.

Vocal processing is tricky and relies largely on the recorded performance/voice, unless ones making sci-fi vocals, which can take lots of processing without ending sounding bad/odd.

If you want to keep the integrity of the original voice, I would experiment with layering differently processed versions of the recording with the original. Or multi-tracking the same line/performance and playing with layering those.

Post examples, if it's something specific you have in mind.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your replies. I took your advice and tried layering this, and it started to sound acceptable. This is the current progress, and I'm still working on the concept:
http://soundcloud.com/george-v/gamesounds-0-5/s-q8Xhq